# Google Sheet Timestamp if Column X updated to a specific Value Y – Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to add a Timestamp in my Column X when the Column O changes its Value to "Y"..

At the moment I am able to get the timestamp into Column X when Column O is updated.
But there is already a formula in the column O, which waits for an event and then automatically inserts a "Y", which Google does not seem to recognize as an update of the column. Now I want my script to recognize when a "Y" is in Column O and then set the timestamp in Column X.

I hope that I have expressed myself understandably.

```
function onEdit(e) {
const s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "März/2023" ) { //checks that we're on Sheet1 or not
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 15 ) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column O
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 9);
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //checks if the adjacent cell is empty or not?
nextCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}
}
```

I have rethought and i update the Column A manually.... Column A can have several values, but the timestamp in X should only be set if the value in Column A is "Bezahlt". I have tried this as in the script below, but that does not work.

```
function onEdit(e) {
const s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "März/2023" ) { //checks that we're on Sheet1 or not
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 1) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column O
var valueO = r.offset(0,0);
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 23);
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' && valueO.getValue === 'Bezahlt' ) //checks if the adjacent cell is empty or not?
nextCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you just need to reread your own script :) the () behind .getValue() where missing..

Got the working code!

```
    function onEdit(e) {
const s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "März/2023" ) { //checks that we're on Sheet1 or not
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 1) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column O
var valueO = r.offset(0,0);
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 23);
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' && valueO.getValue() === 'Bezahlt' ) //checks if the adjacent cell is empty or not?
nextCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}
}
```